# Pattern attribute for not accepting numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

I am trying to learn reqular expressions and apply it to my form using `pattern` attribute.
I have a form which asks for email,firstName ,lastName and password.What I want to do is to prevent lastName and firstName from containing digits.
So here is my code:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" required class="form-control" id='email-input'>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required class="form-control" id='first-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]" title="First name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" required class="form-control" id='last-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]" title="Last name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="form-control" id='password-input'>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success pull-right' value='Complete registration' style="margin-top:0.3em">
</form>
```

However I I fill in all my inputs even If I don't type any number(just fill in a real name) int the 
First Name and the Last Name input I get an error saying:
Please match the requested format.
I would like an explanation.
To better understand what I want to do here is an example:

If input for `first-name` is foo it will not throw an error.

If input is foo1 or 1 or 1foo it will throw an error

Comment: I think you need to replace `pattern="[^0-9]"` with `pattern="[^0-9]*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribizew I will try it but can you explain a little why?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Your pattern `[^0-9]` represents a single non-digit character so it'll allow only a single character. Adding a `*` at the end makes it `[^0-9]*` which can accept a string of non-digit characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, the reason for the error is simple. The regex you wrote is correct such that is does not matches to a character between 0-9. What youre missing is that it is set to match to a single character. Use the `+` keyword to specify one or more characters

> [^0-9] : Match single character not between 0-9
>
> [^0-9]+ : Match one or more characters not between 0-9

If you want more precise control over the numbers of characters allowed

> [^0-9]{1,5} : Will allow minimum 1 and maximum 5 characters

```html
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" required class="form-control" id='email-input'>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required class="form-control" id='first-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]*" title="First name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" required class="form-control" id='last-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]*" title="Last name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="form-control" id='password-input'>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success pull-right' value='Complete registration' style="margin-top:0.3em">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML5 pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) requires a full string input. If you need to accept values not containing digits, you need to match a string with no digits inside. Add `*` after each `[^0-9]` to match 0 or more non-digit chars (anchors are added by default by the engine itself):

```html
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" required class="form-control" id='email-input'>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required class="form-control" id='first-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]*" title="First name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" required class="form-control" id='last-name-input' pattern="[^0-9]*" title="Last name cannot contains any digits">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="form-control" id='password-input'>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success pull-right' value='Complete registration' style="margin-top:0.3em">
</form>
```

Note: you may also use `pattern="\D*"` to shorten it a bit. `\D` matches a non-digit character.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset.

If you know any other regex style, consider that HTML input pattern are always surrounded by *^* and *$*.

Thus, your current expression matches any word with **only one character** not being a digit. Writing **[^0-9]+** will be valid for anything with at least one character and no digit in it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding the [`required`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7_oScn9bTAhUBpY8KHcBKAL4QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_input_required.asp&usg=AFQjCNGVN7nEs7Ws3pW_pqnuxRkD1f-cIw&sig2=weff4pB_9yv6E1wGGMOZKg) attribute .it will not permit the  empty input

***Example for your own error throw***

```js
function check(){
if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value.match(/[0-9]/g))
{
console.log('please enter alphapet only')
}

}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button onclick="check()">check</button>
```

Comment: Sorry.Where I say I don't type any number i mean i enter a string without numbers

Comment: If you add your own error.you need a javascript.It not do with in html only.its default behaviour of the html